# 'SystemCpuLoad' for System CPU usage coming different if called from different JVMS

Tags: java, jvm, cpu-usage, mbeans, sar

I have two JVM's where one JVM(JVM 1) is lightweight and another JVM (JVM 2) does heavy tasks. When I try to get System usage from JVM's by fetching 'SystemCpuLoad', JVM 1 is giving correct CPU values (matching SAR values) and another JVM which does heavy work is giving high CPU usage not matching SAR values.
Followed the below approach :

```
final ObjectName mapMBeanName = new ObjectName( "java.lang:type=OperatingSystem" );
MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
cpu =100.0 * Float.parseFloat( server.getAttribute( mapMBeanName, "SystemCpuLoad" ).toString() );
```

Can anyone help me how can I get correct System CPU usage irrespective of whether the JVM process does the heavy task or lighter task?

Comment: Which OS and JVM version?

Comment: Hi, Linux OS, Java version "1.8.0_241"

Comment: On Linux, JDK reads `SystemCpuLoad` from [`/proc/stat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). This pseudofile contains system-wide statistics, it's the same for all processes. If you don't trust JDK, parse the file on your own (you basically need just the first line starting with `cpu`).